# SQL query : consider the header column part of the script

Tags: sql

I am just wondering if in a SQL script perspective, it is possible to consider the header column itself part of the SQL script.

In an Excel file, it is possible to do it. I am wondering if in SQL script it is possible to do it, too.

In my mind should be something like:

```
case when p.name <> [Header Column] then 'F' else 'T' end as 'Duplicate'
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should illustrate what you want to do/achieve with an example I guess. But it might help to tell you, that tables (and views and query results...) in relational database aren't (like) spreadsheets. They represent relations which are a special form of (multi) sets. There is no "header row" (or rather tuple) in a relation. Relations do belong to a schema though, that denotes, among other things, column (or rather attribute) names. That schema isn't part of the data.

Comment: @stickybit this is the code that I am trying to do                                                                        iif (p.name = [COLUMNHEADER], 'T','F') as 'Duplicate', The outcome should be "T" for True or 'F' for false

Comment: Yeah, that code (which I did see in the OP) doesn't make any sense to me and it doesn't explain what you want to do/achieve logically.

Comment: That's fine..I thought it it is not possible in a sql script anyway..Thanks for helping

Comment: The column name is the bit on the left-hand side of your expressions (p.name). As this cannot change you can hardcode the expression e.g. p.name = 'name'

Comment: thanks for the explanation @NickW. I will try it